# Is it possible to create model and view in Backbone.js with parameters?

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to create model and view in Backbone.js with parameters ?
I try simple like

```
    var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend( {
        initialize: function(test){
        this.set('test',test);
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

but I got message **this.set is not a function**.

Comment: Did you instantiate the model first?  Can you show us code where you get the error?  Also you're missing a } and a ) in your code above. As it stands, that code will not run.

Comment: @tkone I forgot to paste }) but I have in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your example code, but that should work just fine. You also need to account for the model's `attributes` as the first parameter and reference a generic `options` object as the second parameter (see the code here http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-28 )

From your sample code, though, it looks like you're just trying to pass data to the model, which is handled for you automatically.

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var t = new TestModel({foo: "bar"});

console.log(t.get("foo"));
```

Or if you're trying to get some options, you can do this:

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(attrs, options){
    console.log(options.foo);
  }
});

var t = new TestModel(null, {
  foo: "bar"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.  You didn't show enough code, but this works:

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var t = new TestModel({test: 'test'});

t.get('test');
>>> test
```

You can't pass anything into the `initialize` method, but you can pass in a hash when you instantiate the object.

Although, since it doesn't do validation on create (so it will always return a valid model), you're better off doing:

```
var t = new TestModel();
t.set('test', 'test');
```

So in case your value doesn't validate you'll be able to receive an error for it.

Answer (score 0):

The object "this" has all the values as "attributes". So if you want to access any of the attributes,

you can try

`alert(this.attributes.test)`